# Beautifulsoup unable to extract data using attrs=class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am extracting data for a research project and I have sucessfully used `findAll('div', attrs={'class':'someClassName'})` in many websites but this particular website,

[WebSite Link](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n:172282,k%3adigital%20camera&keywords=digital%20camera&ie=UTF8&qid=1343600585)

doesn't return any values when I used attrs option. But when I don't use the attrs option I get entire html dom.

Here is the simple code that I started with to test it out:

```
soup = bs(urlopen(url))
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'data'}):
    print div
```

Comment: If retrieved via urllib2, there is no element with class "data".

Comment: I have used it to other website and it works fine with urllib2

Comment: Maybe Amazon serves different content to full browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code is working fine, with `requests`

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
#grab HTML
r = requests.get(r'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n:172282,k%3adigital%20camera&keywords=digital%20camera&ie=UTF8&qid=1343600585')
html = r.text
#parse the HTML
soup = bs(html)

results= soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'data'})

print results
```

Comment: instead of request i want to use urlopen, and strange enough with urlopen I am unable to get the dom.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `urlopen`. Why not use requests instead? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you or anyone reading this question would like to know the reason that the code wasn't able to find the attrs value using the code you've given (copied below):

```
soup = bs(urlopen(url))
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'data'}):
    print div
```

The issue is when you attempted to create a BeautifulSoup object `soup = bs(urlopen(url))` as the value of `urlopen(url)` is a response object and not the DOM.

I'm sure any issues you had encountered could have been more easily resolved by using `bs(urlopen(url).read())` instead.